# ¿Cuál es la mejor forma de usar "sentir" para pedir disculpa?

Tags: gramática, verbos, subjuntivo

Este es un ejercicio que estoy haciendo en que hay que escoger una de las tres opciones dadas:

> Quieres pedir a tu jefe un par de días libres y quieres hacerlo de una forma amable, ¿qué dirías?
>
> 1. Siento que te llame a estas horas.
> 2. Lo siento que te llame a estas horas.
> 3. Siento llamarte a estas horas.

El problema es que a mi juicio todas son aceptables. Entonces, ¿cuál opción de esas tres es correcta — y por qué?

Comment: Te recomiendo echar un vistazo a [ask]. La próxima vez aventúrate a proponer tú cuál crees que es la respuesta correcta y por qué (mejor equivocarse aquí que en un examen!). Así otros podrán darte mejores respuestas porque entenderán mejor dónde tienes problemas o qué te cuesta entender. Formulada como está ahora esta pregunta, simplemente **le estás pidiendo a alguien que te haga los deberes** y vas a aprender mucho menos en el proceso (o nada). Cuando alguien te explica algo puede ser superobvio, pero no es hasta que te peleas un poco con ello que realmente aprendes, comprendes y retienes.

Comment: Es que he dado la respuesta. En mi opinión las tres eran correctas. Y lo que necesito saber aparte de la que es correcta, ¿por qué las otras dos son incorrectas?

Comment: Puedo entender perfectamente que te encontrases completamente atascado con el ejercicio, pero ten en cuenta que disuadimos las repuestas que no demuestran esfuerzo previo y que frecuentemente animamos a los usuarios a mejorar la calidad de sus preguntas para poder dar respuestas de mayor calidad (Cuál habrías marcado si hubiese sido una pregunta de examen en lugar de los debrees?). Tómatelo como una recomendación para la siguiente vez, no como un reproche. Espero seguir viendo contribuciones tuyas en el futuro!

Comment: No estaba atascado es que veía todas respuestas como correctas y todavía las sigo viendo. La respuesta que una de ellas es correcta no me vale porque quiero saber ¿por qué las otras son incorrectas? Y como nadie todavía ha contestado veo mi pregunta como perfectamente válida

Comment: ¡Me encanta esta pregunta!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Nota antes de empezar**: Quizá quieras echarle una vistazo a [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20683/5481) a una pregunta reciente sobre frases subordinadas ("[déjame pagar vs Deja que pague yo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20681/5481)") que puede estar bastante relacionada con la tuya.

Es normal que esas frases te parezcan todas correctas. Estos son algunos de esos casos excepcionales en que se rompen las reglas, como cuando tienes un verbo irregular (y el caso de estos ejercicios es especialmente rebuscado). Para ti, que estás aprendiendo y aplicas la norma general, es normal que todos parezcan correctos, pues todos respetan la norma. Para un nativo, que aplica la excepción a la norma sin darse cuenta, suenan inmediatamente mal, pero le cuesta razonar el porqué.

> Siento que te llame a estas horas.

Esta frase es gramaticalmente correcta. No hay nada malo hasta que no la pones en el contexto de "**tú** estás llamando a tu jefe". Si quisieras decir

> Siento que (**él o ella**) te llame a estas horas  <sub>I'm sorry (**he or she**) calls you at that time</sub>

la frase sería correcta. El `que` introduce una oración subordinada y usas el subjuntivo. Pero la cosa cambia al usar primera persona en la frase subordinada también. Uno dice "quiero **salir** de esta habitación" pero no "quiero que **yo salga**" aunque esta última frase "siga las normas".

> [...] con muchos de los predicados que imponen subjuntivo a sus subordinadas sustantivas, aparece el infinitivo como única opción **cuando se da la correferencia de sujetos**<sup>1</sup>. Así ocurre con un buen número de los predicados de voluntad y afección. Se dice "Quiero que vayas" y "Quiero ir", pero no "*Quiero que yo vaya" ni "Quiero que vaya" (en la interpretación en la que el sujeto de vaya es de primera persona). La misma alternancia corresponde a "Necesito que salgas" ~ "Necesito salir" ~ "Necesito que (yo) salga". El rechazo del subjuntivo en estos casos, a favor del infinitivo, se extiende a los sustantivos y los adjetivos que introducen complementos oracionales.
>
> <sub>Fuente: [Oraciones subordinadas sustantivas](http://hispanoteca.eu/Foro-preguntas/ARCHIVO-Foro/Subordinadas%20sustantivas%20de%20infinitivo.htm)</sub>

Básicamente, esto está diciendo que hay una excepción a la regla general por que yo puedo decir "(Yo) quiero que (tú) salgas" y uso una subordinada introducida por `que` y verbo en subjuntivo. Si hay concurrencia de sujetos (yo sobre *yo*) ya no uso el subjuntivo (es incorrecto "(yo) quiero que (yo) salga") y me veo obligado a usar una oración subordinada sustantiva de infinitivo

> (yo) quiero **salir**

El ejemplo propuesto en la pregunta se complica un poco más porque "[llamar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NTReP1j)" es transitivo, y necesitas un complemento directo. Pero básicamente esa es la razón por la que decimos

> Siento **llamar**te

(tenemos que añadir el pronombre) y no

> Siento que (yo) llame

Eso explica por qué la primera y segunda son incorrectas y la tercera correcta. **Correferencia de sujetos**.

La segunda añade con ese "lo" una sutileza. Date cuenta que la tercera, que es correcta, podría haber sido tanto

> Siento llamarte a estas horas.

como

> Lo siento **por** llamarte a estas horas.

Es decir, la segunda es incorrecta por el uso de subjuntivo cuando hay correferencia de sujetos, pero al añadir ese `lo` la cosa cambia, porque de hecho "lo" significaría "llamarte a estas horas"

> Siento llamarte a estas horas. De verdad que **lo** siento.

Así que si introduces el `lo` tienes que cambiar la estructura de tu frase subordinada. Ya no introduces una frase subordinada sustantiva de infinitivo y ese `por` introduce o explica la causa. De lo contrario `lo` y "llamarte a estas horas" son redundantes ya que se refieren a lo mismo (con la sutileza de que para usar `lo` deberías haber hecho referencia antes la causa).

---

<sub>1- "Correferencia de sujetos" viene a significar que el agente y el sujeto paciente son el mismo, como en *yo me peino* o *yo me lavo*.</sub>

Comment: Quiero expresar mi agradecimiento por esta respuesta y que a mí, como angloparlante, me ha aclarado mucho. En unos cuatro minutos usted ha explicado este concepto gramatical mejor que mi profesor.

Answer (score 0):

La opción correcta es la 3.

En la primera, nadie dice "Siento que te llame", sino siento llamarte.

En la segunda, el "Lo" es redundante y hace referencia a "que te llame a estas horas".

Comment: ¿Qué es incorrecto en "Siento que te llame"?

Comment: Hay que tener cuidado con las afirmaciones *nadie dice* porque depende del uso regional. Por ejemplo en mi país de repente de usa *siento que te...*; es más fácil dar algún indicio de uso regional o simplemente remitirse a ello en caso de no estar seguro.

Comment: -1. Creo que esta respuesta es un poco vaga y debería elaborarse un poco más. No basta con dar la respuesta para su ejercicio, hay que conseguir que el OP comprenda por qué dos de esas frases no están bien formadas: qué reglas se aplican y qué sutilezas hay. No basta con "la gente no habla así en español". Eso no te ayudaría a ti a aprender otro idioma tampoco. Por qué se usa la forma que sugieres? Qué es exactamante incorrecto en las otras? Mira el comentario del OP a tu respuesta. Si se mejoran esas cosas, cambiaré mi respuesta a +1.

Answer (score 0):

La frase ideal, a mi aviso, sería

> Siento haberte llamado a estas horas.

Pero esa frase no era una de las opciones, así que vamos a evaluar las tres opciones que te dieron.  Se puede descubrir la solución eliminando las opciones subóptimas.

> 1. Siento que te llame a estas horas.
> 2. Lo siento que te llame a estas horas.
> 3. Siento llamarte a estas horas.

El (1) y el (2) no funcionan muy bien porque *Siento que* se tiene que seguir por un sujeto diferente, por ejemplo

> Siento que tengas tan mala opinión de mí.  (*Yo* siento, *tú* tienes mala opinion.  *Yo* ≠ *tú*.)

Eso deja el (3), que no contradice ninguna regla o convenio.