# ¿Qué significa "me alegro mucho de que mi hermano tenga un mejor empleo"?

Tags: verbos, subjuntivo

Estoy leyendo sobre los [usos del subjuntivo](http://www.elsubjuntivo.com/usos.html) y en la sección *Para expresar emoción o sentimiento* se menciona este ejemplo:

> Yo me alegro mucho de que mi hermano **tenga** un mejor empleo.

¿Qué significa la frase? Se me ocurren las siguientes hipóetesis:

1. Me alegro porque mi hermano **YA tiene** este empleo.

o

2. Me alegro porque mi hermano **va a tener** este empleo.

o

3. Me alegro **para que** mi hermano **tenga** este empleo. (O sea mi alegría es la condición gracias a la cual mi hermano podrá tener este empleo)

Comment: Por favor, dale a [edit] para mejorar la pregunta exponiendo tus hipótesis. Te será útil pasar por el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: No estoy haciendo mis deberes. Estoy leyendo sobre los usos del subjuntivo http://www.elsubjuntivo.com/usos.html Alli hay ejemplos y como no entiendo completamente el significado pido ayuda para aclararme. Aparte de eso he expuesto 2 hipótesis y ahora tengo la tercera

Comment: Ajá, entiendo. Así como lo planteaste, parecía un copia-pega del enunciado. Edito y reabro, gracias por la explicación

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay una diferencia entre

> Yo me alegro mucho de que mi hermano **tenga** un mejor empleo.

y

> Yo me alegro mucho de que mi hermano **vaya** a tener un mejor empleo.

En las dos se usa subjuntivo, pero creo que de esta forma queda más claro si ya tiene o no el trabajo. También:

> Me alegro mucho de que mi hermano tenga un empleo mejor ahora. El que tenía hace tres años pagaba muy poco.

Tu hermano ha tenido ese puesto por tres años. No es nuevo, pero el subjuntivo expresa emoción o sentimiento. Podrías usar "tenga" también, si lo tiene ya *casi* asegurado.

Con "vaya a tener" sí expresas una condición en el futuro. La diferencia es sutil, pero con "tenga" lo tiene ya (incluso lo ha tenido por un tiempo) o es casi seguro.

Comment: Todo esto será cierto pero creo que no llegaste a contestar la duda precisa que tenía Ruslan.  Lo que él quería hacer era descifrar la frase original -- no editarla.

Answer (score 1):

> La frase original: **Yo me alegro mucho de que mi hermano tenga un mejor empleo.**
>
> Hipótesis (1): Me alegro porque mi hermano YA tiene este empleo.
>
> Hipótesis (2): Me alegro porque mi hermano va a tener este empleo.
>
> Hipótesis (3): Me alegro para que mi hermano tenga este empleo. (O sea mi alegría es la causa que mi hermano pueda tener este empleo)

Creo que entiendo tu duda.  Bueno, veremos si sí....

La frase original bien puede significar (1) o (2), pero no puede significar el (3).

Si agregamos un adverbio, será claramente el (2):

> Yo me alegro mucho de que mi hermano *pronto* tenga un mejor empleo.

---

Comentario para tí: A veces el español es así de impreciso.  Es un poco como una novela donde el fin del tramo no está completamente claro, y se deja algo a la imaginación del lector.

Comentario para @prgrm: *"la pregunta no da para más"*: De acuerdo.  Traté de ampliar un poquito más porque Ruslan seguía con una duda, pero apoyé tu respuesta con mi voto.

Comentario para los demás expertos que participan aquí: Al igual que @prgrm, no tengo gran cosa que ofrecer para justificar mi conclusión.  Solo mi intuición y un poquito de lógica.  Pero a veces se puede hacer un aporte aún así.

Answer (score -1):

La frase significa las dos primeras opciones. En la segunda implica que tiene el trabajo asegurado pero aún no ha comenzado.

La tercera no es correcta bajo ningún concepto.

Comment: Sería interesante que añadieras mayores explicaciones para que la respuesta sea más útil. Esto quiere decir incluir fragmentos de teoría, ejemplos...

Comment: @fedorqui me gustaria añadir más pero la pregunta no da para más.

Comment: Entiendo, pero fíjate que en la pregunta de ayer también parecía lo mismo y [Diego contestó](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20684/1674) con algo muy sustancial. Nótese que no es obligatorio hacer lo que comento, pero si queremos ayudar a alguien a aprender los detallitos del español es bueno que nos pongamos en su piel dando detalles de _por qué_ algo es así, en lugar de _qué_ es correcto.

Comment: Es que es lo que no llego a entender. Si las primeras dos opciones son correctas entonces el hermano 1. Ya tiene trabajo 2. Todavía no lo tiene. Pero él no puede tener y no tener trabajo al mismo tiempo. ¿Puede explicarme un poco más?

Comment: Parece que empiece a entender. Él ya tiene o casi tiene (lo tiene asegurado)

Comment: Por todo lo dicho anteriormente, voto negativamente esta respuesta.

Comment: @RuslanMukhanov me da la impresión de que la 3ra expresión es una traducción literal de *I'm glad for my brother to have this job* que vendría siendo idiomáticamente *me alegro que mi hermano tenga este empleo.*